# How to create a process in Foregorund in Virtualbox guest Ubuntu using VirtualBox API

Tags: c++, ubuntu, com, virtualbox

I am using Visual Studio to develop a software which creates a process inside a VirtualBox guest OS Ubuntu. I tried to implement it using C++ with Windows as Host OS.

Using the code below, i am able to create process inside the Ubuntu but The GUI does not run. The process only runs in the background. I can see that when I run

```
 ps -ax
```

inside the Ubuntu terminal.

I even tried using EXPORT $DISPLAY=:0 in the Ubuntu program but it doesn't make any difference.

Following is the code for Windows host

```
BSTR userName = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR("root");
BSTR password = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR("saa");
BSTR sessionName = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR("session1");
BSTR processName = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR("/home/parthkumar/p");
ProcessWaitResult processWaitResult;
ProcessCreateFlag processCreateFlag = ProcessCreateFlag_WaitForStdOut;

long it = 0;
ULONG pidd = 0L;



do {
    guest->CreateSession(userName, password, NULL, NULL, &guestSession);

    CComSafeArray<int> flags(1);
    flags[0] = processCreateFlag;

    resultCode = guestSession->ProcessCreate(processName, NULL, NULL, flags, 0, &guestProcess);
    if (!SUCCEEDED(resultCode))
    {
        printf("\nThe Guest Process could not be created\n");
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
        guestProcess->WaitFor(ProcessWaitForFlag_Start, 0, &processWaitResult);
        printf("\n\nprocess wait result %d", processWaitResult);

        resultCode = guestProcess->get_PID(&pidd);
        printf("\n\npid is %d", pidd);
    }

} while (0);
/*SafeArrayDestroy(flags);
SafeArrayDestroy(arguments);*/


return 0;
}
```

The Following is the code in the Ubuntu Process

```
 int main()
 {
       printf("hello world");
      system("bash parth.sh");
      return 0;
 }
```

Following are the contents of parth.sh

```
 export DISPLAY=:0
 gnome-terminal
```

How do I bring this process to foreground or change the code the run it in foreground?

Any Ideas??
Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Sorry for the left out details. I have added more details. Tell me if this one sounds ok?